# Android: Unfortunately, Sample has stopped

Tags: android

Estou criando uma aplicação mas no caso esta dando problema na hora de rodar até um certo ponto, eu quero transformar geoi = 0; e mati = 0; , e quando eu adicionar qualquer numero na edittext ele vai colocar esse número dentro da int  geoi e mati que no caso é igual a 0. Qual o erro no meu codigo ? Por que está dando Unfortunately ?

```
package com.gustavo.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CheckBox g;
    CheckBox m;
    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bacon();

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String counter = num.getText().toString();

                int counterAsInt = Integer.parseInt(counter);

                int geoi = 0;
                int mati = 0;           



                  if(g.isChecked()){
                      geoi += counterAsInt;
                      say.setText("Geo" + geoi);
                  }
                  else if(m.isChecked()){  
                    mati += counterAsInt;
                    say.setText("Math" + mati);
                  }

            }
        });
    }
    public void bacon() {
        g = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        m = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
    }

}
```

Comment: Gustavo, você precisa incluir o `stacktrace` do erro que aparece no log da sua `IDE`. Sem isso não dá pra adivinhar qual erro ocorreu no seu código, porque a princípio não tem nenhum.

Comment: @Gustavo Dibai tenta fazer com que sua classe herde de Activity.. public class MainActivity extends Activity.. outra diga e verificar os nomes no findViewById pra ver ser não errou o id

Comment: ActionBarActivity tem os mesmos metodos de Activity porém alguns complementares.

Comment: Wakim vou tentar isso vlw

Comment: @Wakim você poderia me ajudar a fazer o stacktrace ? Dentro do meu codigo ?

Comment: Olhe o **LogCat** da IDE, precisa estar com o dispositivo plugado na USB e com o ADB rodando.

Comment: AndroidRuntime
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)

Comment: Copie o `stacktrace` inteiro, ele possui dezenas de linhas, em sua pergunta para melhor visualização.

Comment: @GustavoDibai, o `stacktrace` já está sendo exibido, mas precisa verificar na sua `IDE`, qual esta usando?

Comment: @Wakim Aee acho que eu achei **09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1.5"
09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
09-29 20:07:22.892: E/AndroidRuntime(1437):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
**

Comment: @Wakim acho que eu já entendi o erro, eu estou colocando numeros decimais, e é so de numeros inteiros mais e agora o que eu fasso para funcionar os decimais também ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo Stacktrace postado, o problema é que está convertendo uma `String` no formato `float` para um `int`.

Não sei se sua intenção é tratar o valor do campo como número inteiro ou como número decimal.

Para tratar como número inteiro você deve fazer:

```
int counterAsInt = (int) Float.parseFloat(counter);
```

Com isso, o valor `String` de `counter` vai ser convertido para número decimal (`float`) e depois convertido em inteiro através de um *casting*, com isso ele irá descartar a parte decimal.

Se quiser tratar como número decimal você deve ignorar o casting e usar uma variável do tipo `float`, dessa forma:

```
float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);
```

E ai mudar o tipo das demais variáveis `int` usadas no cálculo para `float` também:

```
float geof = 0f;
float matf = 0f;           

if(g.isChecked()){
    geof += counterAsFloat;
    say.setText("Geo" + Float.toString(geof));
} else if(m.isChecked()){  
    matf += counterAsFloat;
    say.setText("Math" + Float.toString(matf));
}
```

O uso do `Float.toString` é opcional, mas deixa claro que esta convertendo uma variável do tipo `float` para sua representação em `String`.

Comment: Valeu ajudou muito :)